# How do I error handle my discord bot not being able to join a voice channel?

Tags: discord.js

Some users get an error saying `Missing Permissions` which means that the bot isn't able to locate the channel, there are three ways of being able to fix this error, two ways are below here, the first option isn't the best option. The 3rd option is the answer below.

```
if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('VIEW_CHANNEL')) {
        return message.channel.send('I can\'t find the voice channel, make sure I have the `View Channel` permission.')
}

// The member has to be in a voice channel
if (!message.member.voice.channel.permissionsFor(<Client>.user).has('VIEW_CHANNEL')) {
        return message.channel.send('I can\'t find the voice channel, make sure I have the `View Channel` permission.')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it can be variable, some voice channels allowed some are not,

So you need to have an instance of a specific `VoiceChannel` and then you can use `.joinable` property

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=joinable

```js
const channel = <VoiceChannel>
if(!channel.joinable) {
       return message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: colours.error,
                description: 'I can\'t find the voice channel, make sure I have the `View Channel` permission.',
            },
        });
}
```